# Creating Objects out of the registry using C#

Tags: c#

So here is what I am trying to accompish.  I have several logging keys in the Registry for each specific process.

I would like to make an object out of these when the program starts so I can access the values when I need, so basically they are preloaded.

Here is what I have got thus far my class:

```
class LoggingInfo
{

    //field data

    private String LogName;
    private int DailyFile;


    // Constructors. 
    public LoggingInfo() { }
    public LoggingInfo(String LogName, int DailyFile)
    {
        this.LogName = LogName;
        this.DailyFile = LogDailyFile;

    }

}
```

So how do I get the properties from the registry for say the LoggingInfo Object?   In my main program do I need to pass anything in?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want. There is no question here yet.

Comment: I want to build objects from the windows registery.

Comment: the registry doesn't contain objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
private const string m_sKeyPathString = "XXX\\YYY";
private const string m_sKeyVal = "MY_VAL";

RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(m_sKeyPathString);

if(key == null)
    key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(m_sKeyPathString);

if(key.GetValue(m_sKeyVal) != null)
    string sMyString = (string)key.GetValue(m_sKeyVal);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the string (convert to int, double, date, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Microsoft.Win32 namespace, specifically class RegistryKey.

You are going to need to connect to the registry manually (maybe through a loop?) to the registry key where you are saving your keys and instance your class for each key you find.

Comment: I know.  I have several key locaitons, that i would like to use as propertys within my object i want to create.

Comment: There is no automatic process that turns registry keys into objects. You will have to open your root key and from there loop through each key, creating an instance of your class and initializing properties.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0520__Windows/Loopthroughthevaluesinsideakeyanddisplay.htm) should help.  Instead of displaying the values, set them in your object.

Answer (score 0):

Registry is not composed of [POCO's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) so you would have to implement yourself.

There is a project that has [Poco::Util::WinRegistry](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.WinRegistryKey.html). It may be worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

As @0A0D said, the registry does not store objects.  However, it can store strings.  If you *serialize* objects to JSON or XML strings and store them in the registry, you can later load the string value from those same keys, then *deserialize* the string into objects.

You may want to search MSDN for more information about serialization.  For example, the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) article would be a good place to start.